# Stata - efficiently appending 200+ files (my method takes hours)

Tags: append, sas, stata

I am trying to append approx. 200 files using Stata.  Below I have provided the code I am using to append.  The issue is that it is taking too long -- over 5 hours to do.  The ultimate appended file has over 28 million observations and is about 2GB in size.  I think the issue might be that it is saving every time and hence takes too long.  I also tried using the tempfile mode -- but that also takes long.  My colleague, on the other hand, did the same append in minutes using SAS.  I have provided his code below as well.  I would very much appreciate if someone could show me how to do it efficiently in Stata -- so that it would not take hours.  Thanks much!

My Stata code:

```
file close _all
    file open myfile using "$OP\filelist_test.txt", read    
    file read myfile line

    cd "$OP"    
    insheet using "`line'", comma clear
    tostring optionconditioncode, replace

    save "$data\options_all", replace

    file read myfile line

    while r(eof)==0{
        insheet using "`line'", comma clear
        tostring optionconditioncode, replace
        append using "$data\options_all"
        save "$data\options_all", replace

        file read myfile line
        }

    file close myfile
```

My colleague's SAS code:

```
data all_text (drop=fname);
      length myfilename $100;
      set dirlist;
      filepath = "&dirname\"||fname;
      infile dummy filevar = filepath length=reclen end=done missover dlm=',' firstobs=2 dsd;
      do while(not done);
        myfilename = filepath;
        input var1
                    var2
                    var3
                    var4
          output;
      end;
```

Comment: One option might be concatenating the files (e.g. using `cat` on unix like systems) and then reading the joined file into Stata.  You might also consider using `rmsg` to time the commands and isolate the lines that are taking the longest and therefore ripe for optimization.

Comment: Thanks!  I also got the following response on Stata forum which did the job in under 10 minutes.  http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-12/msg00808.html

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it on SO.  That would help others who will end up here looking for a solution.

Comment: See Statalist policy on cross-postings at http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/resources/statalist-faq/#crossposting

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the OP has not been around lately. The solution given by Robert Picard from the Stata forum [link](http://stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-12/msg00808.html) that the OP has provided is as follows:

```
> Take a look at -filelist- from SSC. It can create a Stata dataset of
> files (with full path). The help file has an example that does what
> you want efficiently. Here's a copy:
>
> use "csv_datasets.dta", clear
> local obs = _N
> forvalues i=1/`obs' {
>   use "csv_datasets.dta" in `i', clear
>   local f = dirname + "/" + filename
>   insheet using "`f'", clear
>   tempfile save`i'
>   save "`save`i''"
> }
>
> use "`save1'", clear
>   forvalues i=2/`obs' {
>   append using "`save`i''"
> }
```